# nullable GSI vs Sparse Index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I know AWS questions are rarely getting an answer but I will try my luck. It's a pretty easy  one but I cannot find an answer to that

Let's say I have the simples table ever with 2 'column'. `token`(Partition Key) and `userId`

What I want is to have a 1000 of tokens, and once a user signs up, a token will get assigned to the user. Basically the `userId` property in the table will be populated. Also, I want to be able to query, not scan, by both `token` and `userId`

In order to query by `userId` I can use it as a GSI, BUT it states that GSIs should not be null. All my entries in the beginning will have the `token` property, but the `userId` will be empty until it actually gets assigned.

What can I use for this scenario? I thought about a Sort Key as it's a Sparse Index, but as far as I know I cannot query ONLY by the Sort Key itself.

Comment: Keep the 1000 tokens in a list in memory - and then write the token,user and user,token combo to dynamo only when assigned -then you can query by eithet

Comment: Alao keys must be unique -so if multiple users can have the same token - you need to deal with that case as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you’re thinking there and create a GSI based on the userID. For the base table don’t include a userID attribute at all until the token has one. This isn’t relational. You don’t need every row to have all attributes. Only the key attributes have to be provided.

So:

- Early on all items are just the token attributes with no other attributes
- You have a GSI with userID as its PK
- Then add userID attributes to the tokens when assigned, and that will get propagated to the GSI